# LaTeX in R Notebook not rendering properly in HTML (hats are skewed to the right)

Tags: html, r, latex, r-markdown, rnotebook

When I output an [r](/questions/tagged/r) Notebook to [html](/questions/tagged/html), and use [latex](/questions/tagged/latex), most of the output renders fine.

When I use hats though, it's not lined up properly on the character I'm 'hatting'.

For example:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

Hello Everyone, $\pi = 3.14159...$ but my estimate is $\hat{\pi}=3.13$
```

**Outputs into an HTML file:**

[image: Output]

Even though, when I hover over the [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) in the code, it renders properly:

[image]

Another thing I now notice is that, the [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) output font when I hover is nicer than the HTML output, is it possible to change the HTML output font to the 'hovering' font?

**EDIT:** My OS and software versions are MacOS Catalina 10.15.3 with RStudio version 1.1.456

Comment: Your example works fine for me on a Mac .. what is your setup you are using?

Comment: My OS and software versions are MacOS Catalina 10.15.3 with RStudio version 1.1.456, I've edited the post with this information.

Comment: You should update your RStudio version because it inherits a newer pandoc version. Also update all your packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed an RStudio update, and it solved the problem. I'd tried updating RStudio through the application, but since I had the option 'Ignore Updates' it would always notify me that I had the latest version, so I had to download the .dmg from the website and re-install.

If anyone can help me change the font though, I'd really appreciate it.